# Name <name> is not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to make two dropdown lists that will be populated from a database. For some reason it says that my dropdown lists in the VB.net code are not declared. it should take the declaration of AcadYrDDL and TermDDL from the ASP code right?

Im relatively new to asp and vb.net; need some help. Also, It would be great if you guys could point out certain mistakes that i have made.

ASP:

```
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="AcadYrDDL" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="option" Value=""/>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="TermDDL" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="option" Value=""/>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button runat="server" type="button" id="viewButton" class="btn btn-default" value="View">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp View
    </asp:Button>
</form>
```

VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient



Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Populate1()
        Populate2()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Populate1()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT term FROM CADETCRSE", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnString")))
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        AcadYrDDL.DataSource = ddlValues
        AcadYrDDL.DataValueField = ""
        AcadYrDDL.DataTextField = "Acadyr"
        AcadYrDDL.DataBind()

        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Populate2()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT AcadYr FROM CADETCRSE", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnString")))
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        TermDDL.DataSource = ddlValues
        TermDDL.DataValueField = ""
        TermDDL.DataTextField = "Current term"
        TermDDL.DataBind()

        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Dispose()
    End Sub





End Class
```

Comment: When you add a control to the aspx page and save, it is included in the designer of page. Check out  if your DropDownList is declared there (in solution explorer, file Default.aspx.designer.vb)

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601711/two-values-inside-a-combobox-in-vb/31601894?noredirect=1#comment51155016_31601894

Answer (score 0):

The `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` should be fields from your data base call. If not explicitly setting `DataValueField` just leave it be and don't try setting it to an empty string. Your final code should look like:

```
Public Sub Populate1()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT term FROM CADETCRSE", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnString")))
    cmd.Connection.Open()

    Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    AcadYrDDL.DataSource = ddlValues
    AcadYrDDL.DataTextField = "term" 'This is the field in your database call
    AcadYrDDL.DataBind()

    cmd.Connection.Close()
    cmd.Connection.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Sub Populate2()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT AcadYr FROM CADETCRSE", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnString")))
    cmd.Connection.Open()

    Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    TermDDL.DataSource = ddlValues
    TermDDL.DataTextField = "AcadYr" 'As this is what you have returned in your 
    TermDDL.DataBind()

    cmd.Connection.Close()
    cmd.Connection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this definitely helped me. But I dont think this solves the main problem which is AcadYrDDL and TermDDL being undeclared.

Comment: Do you get autocomplete for your DDLs? I.e. if in the code behind you put `AcadYrDDL.` do you get autocomplete options for methods and properties? When do you get the error? On build? Or when trying to view the page? It looks like you might have an issue with name space and the name `_default`. Try cleaning the project (right click the project in solution explorer and click "clean" then rebuild. Also try testing in a new page with a different name.

Comment: Yea for some reason I think it should autocomplete but it isnt. The error comes out the moment I type the code. AcadYrDDL and TermDDL is underlined red.

I have already changed the name _default to dropdown as the vb and asp file is named dropdown. Also, 

I dont think vstudio 2008 has the clean feature as i couldnt find it. Im required to use vstudio 2008 and no other version.

Comment: Don't just rename, that can break things. Unless you know what you are doing leave anything auto generated by visual studio alone. Just start with a brand new page for testing purposes and work backwards from there. It's been a while since I've used VS2008 so this question may not apply, is your project set up as a web site or web application?

Comment: oh. my bad. default is on _Default. The project is set up as a web site.

Did I do things right code-wise? So it means the problem has something to do with the version of VS that im using?

Comment: The project being a website explains the lack of  "clean". The code is basically OK. I've had issues similar to this with pages named "default" and therefore with a _default class. That is why I suggested adding a new page to test from there. Alos just try deleting the problem page, quit VS. Start it up again and start with a fresh new page.

Comment: Tried doing that just now. Nothing seems to be different.