# Two values inside a combobox in vb

Tags: vb.net, combobox

i want to create a combobox with two fields inside.

so far, this is my code.
it can only display the area number but i want to display also the area name in a single line. can anyone help me with this? any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you so much

```
  Sub getarea()
    Try
        Call MyConnection()
        Sql = "select AREA_NO as 'Anum', AREA_NAME as 'Aname', AREA_LOCX as 'Alocx' from area"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, Con)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Try
            Dim comboarea As New DataTable
            comboarea.Load(reader)
            cboareano2.DataSource = comboarea
            cboareano2.DisplayMember = "Anum"
            cboareano2.ValueMember = "Anum"
            cboareano2.SelectedIndex = -1

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub cboAreaNo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboAreaNo.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        Call MyConnection()
        Sql = "select AREA_NAME, AREA_LOCX from area where AREA_NO=@Anum"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        With cmd
            .CommandText = Sql
            .Connection = Con
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Anum", cboAreaNo.SelectedValue)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Try
            If reader.Read Then
                txtlocx.Text = reader.GetString(1)
                reader.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        Con.Close()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are makes some mistake in binding the `combobox`, you are
>   assigning `Anum` to both `DisplayMember` field as well as to the
>   `ValueMember` field. so the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue both are`
>   the Area_Number`.

So what you have to do is that:
Recode the binding snippet as follows

```
    Dim comboarea As New DataTable
    comboarea.Load(reader)
    cboareano2.DataSource = comboarea
    cboareano2.DisplayMember = "Aname"
    cboareano2.ValueMember = "Anum"
    cboareano2.SelectedIndex = -1
```

- Now you can take the Area_Name through `cboareano2.Text` or
  `cboareano2.SelectedItem.Text`
- You will get the Area_Code through `cboareano2.SelectedValue`
- If you want to display both the code and name then make change in the query as follows:

  ```
   Sql = "select AREA_NO as 'Anum', CONCAT(AREA_NO,'-',AREA_NAME) as 'Aname', AREA_LOCX as 'Alocx' from area"
  ```

  and bind the result as i mentioned above.